# Showing surjectivity of ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $$A=\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i X^{i}\in R[X]\mid n\in\mathbb{N}, a_i\in R, a_1=0 \right\}\subseteq R[X]$$ be a subring of a commutative ring $R[X]$.

Now I have to show that 
$$\varphi:R[X_1, X_2]\rightarrow A\\
f(X_1,X_2)\mapsto f(X^2, X^3)$$

is surjective.

I think it is basically a technicality, but I just wont get it.
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The monomial $X_1^{\alpha_1}X_2^{\alpha_2}$ with $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\geq 0$ is mapped to $(X^2)^{\alpha_1}(X^3)^{\alpha_2} = X^{2\alpha_1+3\alpha_2}$. The exponent $2\alpha_1+3\alpha_2$ can be any integer $\geq 0$ but not be equal to $1$. This implies the surjectivity.

Note that for each even integer $n\geq 0$, $n=2\alpha_1$, and for each odd integer $n\geq 3$, $n=2\alpha_1+3$.